# How to add a loader gif while Angular resolvers are in progress

Tags: angular

Is it possible to add a loader gif on the page while the server calls are in progress for a resolver? Resolvers are on many pages and all the loader gifs would be the same so is there a global way of doing this rather than adding code on every template?

It is possible to subscribe to the route change event:

```
router.events.subscribe(evt => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // Do what you need to here
    }
});
```

But I don't know where to put this. As for a global loader gif maybe the root component could be accessed by resolvers?

Comment: I don't think, there is an other way, than adding code to every template.

Comment: Create a wrapper around the http provider, and do it from there. Then your templates can do an `*ngIf` on your wrappers status

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this on you app Component or the Main Component that is bootstrapped by your application.

```
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationError, NavigationCancel, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
loading = false;
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.forEach((event) => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  });
}
```

Add this to the app.component template

```
<div *ngIf ="loading" class ="main">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now make use of Router Resolve to display spinner when Router resolve is in Progress.

You can find the working example in this app [Football Scores](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/FootBallScores) . It uses Lazy loading as well as Router Resolve to load data and show this spinner.

Comment: I donot know why your question was dv. it should not have been